# SXA Upgrade gives warning "Sitecore Experience Accelerator Content Upgrade Required"

Tags: sxa

I did an upgrade to SXA from version 1.6 to version 1.7.

After publishing my site, I got the warning message

> Sitecore Experience Accelerator Content Upgrade Required

with an upgrade button. but when i click upgrade and open the Powershell script results i find it empty, it doesn't contain any upgrade steps!

However, i still get the same warning message even when i create a new site or a new tenant.
Any clue why i keep getting this warning although the Powershell script results is empty ?

Comment: Did you perform any synchronization after the upgrade procedure?

Comment: Same issue happened for me. I had to lower the version number for the upgrade to run steps.

Comment: @DawidRutkowski No i haven't.
turned out that it is an issue with 1.6 to 1.7 upgrade that there were no upgrade steps for this upgrade path so i had to change it manually by navigating to:
 /sitecore/system/Settings/Foundation/Experience Accelerator/Upgrade/Current

and changing the number from 1600 to 1700.
It worked successfully for me.

Comment: I've sent a note to our QAs to check this. I will keep you updated.

Comment: We've created an issue in our backlog for this - it's a bug.

Comment: @AmiraElEwady please add your solution as a self answer to the question. It will be useful to others.

Answer (score 3):

Turned out this is a known issue with 1.6-to-1.7 upgrade. There were no upgrade steps for this upgrade path, so just find this item :

/sitecore/system/Settings/Foundation/Experience Accelerator/Upgrade/Current.

and manually increase the number from 1600 to 1700