# Getting error "Unable to establish the current or required content version. Contact your system administrator"

Tags: sxa, migration

A project migrated from 8.2 to 9.3 have error blocks on content editor and experience editor(please take reference from the screenshot below)
I have tried below options but still, the issue is there:

1. Go to below component in CMS and manually increase the number from 1600 to 1700, as per [this question](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/11736/sxa-upgrade-gives-warning-sitecore-experience-accelerator-content-upgrade-requi)

/sitecore/system/Settings/Foundation/Experience Accelerator/Upgrade/Current.

**Issue**: I am not able to find the above component

2. Click on the Upgrade link in the error message, this should open the upgrade tool. Here is the [reference](https://alan-null.github.io/2017/04/sxa-upgrade-tool) link.

**Issue**: I am not seeing an Upgrade link in the error message.

[image]
[image: Error in Xperience editor]

Comment: did you upgrade the SXA as well?

Comment: we didn't upgrade the SXA

Comment: It was not used in 8.2 or now not even in 9.3..is there any way to disable SXA module? or just remove these errors?

Comment: For others who face this issue, try removing all .XA. dlls and merging your web.config in a vanilla web.config..and add only dll which are coming up in error(for me it was 2 XA related dll)..then you should be good.